# Linking error while using static library linkage

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, linkage

This might have been asked previously, however, I found it only in context of Classes, and this is not the case.

**Utils.h**

```
#ifndef _UTILS_H_
#define _UTILS_H_

#include <cmath>

//is 'x' prime?
bool isPrime(long long int x);

//find the number of divisors of 'x' (including 1 and x)
int numOfDivisors(long long int x);

#endif //_UTILS_H_
```

**Utils.cpp**

```
#include "Utils.h"

bool isPrime(long long int x){
if (x < 2){
    return false;
}
long double rootOfX = sqrt( x );
long long int flooredRoot = (long long int)floor ( rootOfX );

for (long long int i = 2; i <= flooredRoot; i++){
    if (x % i == 0){
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
}


int numOfDivisors(long long int x){
if (x == 1){
    return 1;
}

long long int maxDivisor = (x / 2) + 1;
int divisorsCount = 0;
for (long long int i = 2; i<=maxDivisor; i++){
    if (x % i == 0){
        divisorsCount++;
    }
}

divisorsCount += 2; //for 1 & x itself
return divisorsCount;
}
```

These two files have been compiled with Visual Studio 2012 in Debug mode as a static library.
Now I try to use them in a separate project, let's call it MainProject:
1. Add the "Utils.vcproj" to MainProject solution.
2. Make MainProject to depend on Utils
3. In "Properties"->"Linker"->"Input"->"Additional Dependencies" put the path to Utils.lib

Here is the main which uses Utils:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "..\Utils\Utils.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){


cout << "num of divisors of " << 28 << ": " << numOfDivisors(28) << endl;

//this part is merely to stop visual studio and look at the output
char x;
cin >> x;
return 0;
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl numOfDivisors(__int64)" (?numOfDivisors@@YAH_J@Z) referenced in function _main   G:\ProjectEuler\Problem12\Source.obj    Problem12
```

Why can't it find the code which implements "numOfDivisors"? I have given it the .lib which contains it, moreover - put a dependency on the Utils project itself... 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your library compiled as `C` or as `C++`?

Comment: Where can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like method numOfDivisors() is not defined in you Utils.cpp, can you check it once?

And why is your compiler complaining "G:\ProjectEuler\Problem12\Source.obj"? Where is Source.obj coming from?

You have to specify library path in one field and library name in other field, have you specified both under appropriate settings?

Comment: As far as I know, I can specify .lib full path under "Properties"->"Linker"->"Input"->"Additional Dependencies". At least it worked for me in Visual2010.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the library is correctly built and linked, the next most likely cause of the error is that the function is named something else in the library than it is in the code that links to it.

This could be caused by any number of project settings that affect either name decoration or type names. There's not really any point in guessing from a distance which particular setting is the culprit in your case. You can compare the two projects' properties (either manually or with a diff tool) and try to spot a difference that would result in a different decorated function name.